# Adding variable instead of concatenating with jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `.each()` and grabbing some numbers. I'm doing some math with those numbers and I'm trying to add the result, but instead of adding it's concatenating. Here's my code so far:

```
if (zName == 'Premium') {
    $('.product-total .productitemcell .productitemcell').each(function (index, value) {
        oPrice = parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', ''));
        nPrice = parseFloat(oPrice - (oPrice * (10 / 100))).toFixed(2);
        subTotal += nPrice;
        $(this).html('<s>$' + oPrice + '</s> <span style="color:#ef0f0f;">$' + nPrice + '</span>');
    });
}
console.log(subTotal);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.toFixed()` function returns a string, not a number.

(Also, "oPrice", "nPrice", and "subTotal" should be declared with `var`; perhaps they are in code not shown.)

Converting from the return value of `.toFixed()` won't necessarily preserve any fraction truncation that's taken place. Doing monetary math with JavaScript floating-point math is tricky and error-prone.

Comment: They are declared elsewhere. So i tried doing subtotal+=parseFloat(nPrice); but now i'm getting a Nan error.

Comment: @Damien make sure that you initialize "subTotal" to zero somewhere.

Comment: Awesome! What's funny is that at one point i did initialize it to zero but that didn't work so i moved on. Thanks again!